# MySQL multiple WHERE IN on same column with AND operator

Tags: mysql, where-in

Need some help with MySQL.

I'm building web shop and I'm having problems with filtering search results with multiple WHERE IN clauses on same column.

I have tables **shopitem**, **filter**, **filter_option** and **shopitem_option**.

**shopitem** (Items with name, description, price etc.)

```
id
title
price
```

**filter** (Main filter categories like color, brand, gender, size etc.)

```
id
name
```

**filter_option** (filter options like sizes (S, M, L), colors (black, white) etc.)

```
id
name
filter_id (filter.id)
```

**shopitem_option** (connection between items and options)

```
id
shopitem_id (shopitem.id)
filter_id (filter.id)
filter_option_id (filter_option.id)
```

I have items like various Nike Air shoes with different size, color, gender etc...

So in **shopitem_option** table I have following:

```
id  |  shopitem_id  |  filter_id  |  filter_option_id
-----------------------------------------------------
1   |  Nike Air     |  Color      |  black
2   |  Nike Air     |  Color      |  white
3   |  Nike Air     |  Size       |  40
4   |  Nike Air     |  Size       |  41
5   |  Nike Air     |  Size       |  42
6   |  Nike Air     |  Gender     |  man
```

When I'm creating MySQL query it need to be something like this (*in pure SQL query instead of 'black', 'men' etc. there are IDs of filter_option.id field*)

```
SELECT shopitem.*
FROM shopitem
LEFT JOIN shopitem_option.shopitem_id = shopitem.id
WHERE
    shopitem_option.filter_option_id IN (black) AND 
    shopitem_option.filter_option_id IN (41,42) AND 
    shopitem_option.filter_option_id IN (man)
```

But this does not work. If I search only for *size 40*, or only for *color black*, it will return all shoes sizes 40 or all shoes with black color. But if I combine filter to search items with color black and size 40 it returns empty query results.

So, basically user can search for shoes **WHERE** colors *(black **OR** white)* **AND** size *(41 **OR** 42)* **AND** gender *(male)*. How can i accomplish that ?

Comment: What do you mean by “this does not work”?

Comment: @bfontaine If I search only for size 40, or only for color black, it will return all shoes sizes 40 or all shoes with black color. But if i combine filter to search items with color black and size 40 it returns empty query results...

Comment: Thanks, could you please edit your question to add this? It would help people answering you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this

```
SELECT si.*, GROUP_CONCAT(so.filter_option_id) AS filter_options
FROM shopitem si
LEFT JOIN shopitem_option so ON(so.shopitem_id = si.id)
HAVING
FIND_IN_SET('black', filter_options)
AND  FIND_IN_SET('41', filter_options)
AND FIND_IN_SET('man', filter_options)
GROUP BY si.id
```

For counting the number of si.id from the result you can use like this with subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(res.id) FROM
  (SELECT si.*, GROUP_CONCAT(so.filter_option_id) AS filter_options
   FROM shopitem si
   LEFT JOIN shopitem_option so ON(so.shopitem_id = si.id)
   HAVING
   FIND_IN_SET('black', filter_options)
   AND  FIND_IN_SET('41', filter_options)
   AND FIND_IN_SET('man', filter_options)
   GROUP BY si.id) 
 AS res
```

Comment: It says unknow column 'filter_options' in 'where clause'

Comment: check it now. I changed WHERE to HAVING. It will work now

Comment: It works, thank you! How can i use this in item counting ? If I put COUNT(si.id) instead si.* it return me incorrect count of items.

Comment: you are counting unique id from the output result.. right?

Comment: No, i first run COUNT to count all items, then show only 20 with pagination... Thanks on COUNT query!

Comment: How can you run `group by` after `having` without error?

Answer (score 3):

`IN ... AND IN ...` can't work here, because you tell database to select shopitem_option where filter_option_id should be `black` and `41` for one same record. Use `EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM shopitem i
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM shopitem_option o WHERE i.id = o.shopitem_id AND o.filter_option_id IN (black))
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM shopitem_option o WHERE i.id = o.shopitem_id AND o.filter_option_id IN (41, 42))
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM shopitem_option o WHERE i.id = o.shopitem_id AND o.filter_option_id IN (man))
```

Comment: This is also working, thanks! What about COUNT(shopitem.id) ?

Comment: Don't understand what do you mean.. Using `COUNT(shopitem.id)` will return count of items that match filters.

Comment: Sorry, it works for COUNT(id) also! I used $stmt->fetchColumn(); instead of $stmt->rowCount(); in PDO and it returned wrong number of rows...